# Display errors message form

Tags: forms, symfony, passwords

i am trying to show errors messages at the top on page in my twig view but {{ Form_errors(form)}} don't display password errors! but shows other errors..

```
Form builder

->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
              'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
              'required' => true,
              'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
              'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password').


view :

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}


    {{ form_start(form) }}
          {{ form_widget(form) }}`enter code here`
{{dump(form_errors(form))}}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: you tried with 2 different password and you have no errors? What are the "other errors" displayed?

Comment: Does the Symfony profiler show the errors in the [Form] section ? If so, it's a view problem. If not, it's more about a back-end problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{{dump(form_errors(form.password))}}
```

to display errors specific to the password field